# Masonry grid custom item styling

Tags: css, masonry

Is it possible to format a specific item in a 2 columns masonry grid?
Items are generated dynamically.

What I want to add a `top margin` to may second column first item a margin-top.

here is an example https://jsfiddle.net/4ca1r4rf/ of my masonry grids

```
<main>
     <section></section>
     <section></section>
     <section></section>
     <section></section>
     <section></section>
     <section></section>
     <section></section>
     <section></section>
     <section></section>
</main>


$('main').masonry({
      itemSelector: 'section',
      columnWidth: 'section',
      gutter:50,
      isAnimated:false
});
```

Comment: Do you have any code? What have you tried?

Comment: I will upload some codes

Comment: will each column always be 8 items high? or can it vary?

Comment: it is created dynamically

Comment: Do you want to achieve this? https://jsfiddle.net/4ca1r4rf/1/

Comment: yes this is a valid answer thank you. Can you post it? I would accept